# Error while installing Compass through command prompt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, compass

I am trying to install compass,had downloaded ruby version 22.0 but getting error.I tried to install updates as admin but still getting error.

```
    C:\Ruby22-x64\bin>gem install compass
      ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'compass' (>= 0), here is why:
      Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ECONNRESET
     : An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. -           SSL_connect (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz).
```

Kindly help regarding this.

Comment: try by changing source : `gem install compass --source http://rubygems.org`

Comment: @jonsnow Same error I am getting